# Modal form validation issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-5

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour while validating a modal form.
I try to submit the form twice without entering any value just to test validation.
Validation is server side (I'm not able yet to enable client-side validation with modal form).

The first time the validation error occour, the form is displayd correctly as in the next image:
[image]

But the second time, the form is not rendered as model anymore. It's rendered as in the image below:
[image]

I really don't know where I'm wrong.

Here is my code.

Model

```
public class Gruppo:ClasseBase
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
        
     [Required]
     [StringLength(5,MinimumLength = 1)]
     public string Codice { get; set; }
        
     [Required]
     [StringLength(30,MinimumLength = 2)]
     public string Nome { get; set; }
        
     [Required]
     public byte Progressivo { get; set; }=1;
        
     public virtual ICollection<Livello> Livelli { get; set; }
}
    
    
public class Livello : ClasseBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Codice { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [Range(1,250,ErrorMessage ="{0} deve essere compreso tra {1} e {2}.")]
    public byte Progressivo { get; set; } = 1;
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Gruppo))]
    [Required]
    public int IdGruppo { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Gruppo Gruppo { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using GESTPREF.Models
@using GESTPREF.Helpers
@model  Gruppo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Modifica";
}

<h2>Modifica</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Modifica", "Gruppi", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="row mb-2">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Correggi gli errori:", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Codice)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Codice, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Nome)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Progressivo)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Progressivo, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DataInserimento)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Stato)

    <div class="mb-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="card text-dark mb-3">
            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center m-0 p-1">
                <h5 class="card-title">Livelli</h5>
                
                <!-- custom action link : the first parameter is the css class, the second is the link text, the third is the link title, then there are Action name, Controller name, routvalues and htmlattributes -->
                @Html.BIActionLink("bi bi-plus-circle","Crea","Crea livello", "Crea", "Livelli", new {idGruppo=Model.Id}, new { data_modal="", data_targetPlaceHolder = "elencoLivelliPlaceHolder" ,@class="btn btn-primary"})
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="elencoLivelliPlaceHolder">
                    <!-- render the partial view with the index of levels for the current group  -->
                    @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Livelli", new { idGruppo = Model.Id });}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-save"></i> Salva</button>
}


<!-- contenitore finestra modale -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalForm" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="myModalContent">
                      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modalformbs")
}
```

Livelli Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int idGruppo)
{
    ViewBag.IdGruppo = idGruppo;
    var livelli = db.Livelli.Where(x=>x.IdGruppo == idGruppo).OrderBy(x=>x.Progressivo).ThenBy(x=>x.Codice).ThenBy(x=>x.Nome).ToList();

    return PartialView("_IndexPartial", livelli);
}

public ActionResult Crea(int idGruppo)
{
    Livello livello = new Livello()
    {
        IdGruppo = idGruppo
    };

    return PartialView("_Crea", livello);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Crea(Livello livello)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            livello.DataInserimento = DateTime.Now.Date;
            livello.Stato = EnumStato.Abilitato;
            db.Livelli.Add(livello);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var url = Url.Action("Index", "Livelli", new { idGruppo = livello.IdGruppo });
            return Json(new { success = 1, url = url, ex = "" });
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new {success=0, ex=ex.Message.ToString() });
    }
    return PartialView("_Crea", livello);
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    //a[data-modal] link click cause modal form to show
    $('a[data-modal]').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var url = this.href;
        var targetplaceholder = $(this).attr('data-targetPlaceHolder');

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {

                $("#myModalContent").html(data);

                $('#myModalForm').modal('show');

                attachFormSubmitHandler(targetplaceholder); 
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               
               // Show an error message
                $("#myModalContent").html("Si è verificato un errore.</br> " + error);
                console.log(error);

                // Close the modal after 5 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#myModalForm").modal("hide");
                }, 5000);
            }
        });

    });


});


function attachFormSubmitHandler(targetplaceholder) {

    $('#myModalForm form').on("submit", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);


        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                   
                    $("#myModalForm").modal("hide");
                    //the action method return the url of the method to call to get the partial view for the list of record
                    var url = result.url;
                    
                    if (!targetplaceholder.startsWith('#'))
                        targetplaceholder = '#' + targetplaceholder;
                    //the content of targetplaceholder is rendered with the partial view (list of records).
                    $(targetplaceholder).load(url);
                }
                else {
                
                    // if error occour for validation (for example)
                    $("#myModalContent").html(result);
                   
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {

                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```